# How to get the slug STRING value in django models?

Tags: django, django-models

Basically, I have 3 classes (Vehicle, Car and Motorcycle, these 2 last extend the first one)... In the Vehicle class there's the main_image attribute which is a models.ImageField type, as you can see bellow:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

[...]

    main_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to = 'media/images/' + str(slug) + '/', verbose_name = 'Foto principal',
        null = False
)
```

So, the str(slug) doesn't work properly, 'cause when I upload an image, it is always uploaded to

```
/media/images/<django.db.models.fields.SlugField>
```

when it should actually upload to

```
/media/images/(object-slug-value)/
```

I've tried many different things but any of them worked the way I wanted.

How can I get the string value from the slug attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slug` you are using is the field in your model, not the instance. [`upload_to` takes a callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), which you can use to build the path:

```
def get_path(instance, filename):
    return 'media/images/{}/{}'.format(instance.slug, filename)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_path)
```